# Proof of closed form for finite sums by induction.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, summation, proof-writing, induction

I currently have to do this following proof using induction
(base case, inductive hypothesis required):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n(6i-3)=3n^2, \forall n>1$$

I'm not really sure how to approach this question and currently i've ended up with $$=\frac{6n^2 - 5n}{2}$$ for the summation and don't really know where to go from here (or if that's even correct). Any help about where to go from here or what I did wrong is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: No, it's not correct: It's off by a term involving $n$, after all (and even worse, it's *never* an integer). How did you get to that point?

Comment: Could you show your working so we can be more specific with our answers?

Comment: How do you justify the first step? It makes no sense, you are no longer summing over anything... And where did $n$ go?

Comment: You then proceed correctly, but make a misstep at the second to last step:
\begin{equation}
6\frac{n^2+n}{2}-\frac{6n}{2}=\frac{6n^2+6n}{2}-\frac{6n}{2}=\frac{6n^2+6n-6n}{2}=\frac{6n^2}{2}=3n^2.
\end{equation}
... I seem to be having some problems with LaTex myself. I hope the point is clear.

Comment: Sorry the i & 3 on top of the sums were supposed to be to the right of the sum and there is supposed to be an N instead on top of both the sums instead(if that is what confused you). I just messed up the LaTeX.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own question.

Comment: Alternatively, divide both sides by three. Does that seem familiar?

Answer (score 3):

**Base case:**

For $n=1$ the identity clearly holds:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(6i-3)=6\times1-3=3=3\times1^2=3n^2.$$

**Inductive hypothesis:**

Suppose the identity holds for some natural number $n$. Then for $n+1$
    we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(6i-3)
&=&(6(n+1)-3)+\sum_{i=1}^n(6i-3)\\
&=&(6(n+1)-3)+3n^2=3n^2+6n+3\\
&=&3(n^2+2n+1)=3(n+1)^2,
\end{eqnarray*}
 which show that the identity then also holds for $n+1$.

**Induction:**

By induction the identity holds for all natural numbers.

Comment: You missed the $1$ in base case

Comment: Your welcome....

Answer (score 1):

Is it true for $n=1$?

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^1(6i-3) = 6\cdot 1 - 3 = 3 = 3\cdot 1^2$  Yes, it is true for $n=1$.

Now, supposing that it is true that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(6i-3)=3n^2$ for *some* $n\geq 1$, we are curious whether or not it follows that it will necessarily also be true for $n+1$

I.e. we *want to show* that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(6i-3)=3n^2\Rightarrow \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}(6i-3)=3(n+1)^2$.  To do so, we start at one side and manipulate it using a series of equalities, eventually at the very end arriving at the right hand side, showing the left side equals the right side.  (*do NOT begin with the equality you wish to prove and simply reach a tautology, that is circular logic and invalid*)

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}(6i-3) = 6(n+1)-3 + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(6i-3)$ by simply adding the final term of the summation individually.

Now, we recognize the smaller summation and we know something about it based on our induction hypothesis...

> $\dots=6(n+1)-3+3n^2$ by induction hypothesis

Continuing to simplify:

> $\dots = 6n+6-3+3n^2 = 3n^2+6n+3 = 3(n+1)^2$ which is exactly what we wanted to show.

Thus, by the principle of mathematical induction, the result is true for all $n\geq 1$